# Showing a confirmation dialog on backdropclick or escape key press mat-dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a scenario in which i have a form in a mat-dialog(angular material 2). If the user makes the form dirty and press escape key or press outside the dialog overlay , i want to display a confirmation dialog on the top of the main dialog . I tried subscribing for dialogRef.backdropClick() and dialogRef.beforeClosed() events but didn't worked as expected .Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

How did you use backdropClick?

What you need to do is subscribe to any backdrop click events and then load your confirmation dialog.

You would need to do something like this:

```
dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(result => {
      //open confirmation dialog;
    });
```